# If generated string 'ID' < 4 characters long, how do I throw an exception and regenerate the string ID?

Tags: java

This is a question given to us for a try out assignment.

A random generated number is assigned to the characters "IT" to create an ID for a student after type casting to string. However, if the string length including the "IT" characters is less than 4 characters long, we have to throw a custom exception and recall the method that generates the ID number.

Here is my custom exception

```
import java.lang.Exception;

public class IDInvalidException extends Exception {

    public IDInvalidException(String msg) {
        super(msg);
    }
}
```

Here is the class and function that generates the ID. I have given an upper bound of 100000.

```
import java.util.Random;

public class IDGeneration {

    public String newID() {
        //Generate random value upperbound 100000
        Random rand = new Random();
        int intRandom = rand.nextInt(100000);
        
        //concatanate with ID
        String ID = new String("IT" + String.valueOf(intRandom)); 
        
        return ID;  
    }
}
```

Here is the function inside the 'Weekend' student class that triggers the ID generation and checks for the exception.

```
public class Weekend implements WeekendStudent{
    
    public String generateID() throws IDInvalidException{
        
        String studentID = new String("");
        
        while (studentID.length() < 4) {
            //Create IDGeneration object and studentID string object
            IDGeneration ID = new IDGeneration();
            studentID = ID.newID();
        }
        
        return studentID;
        
    }
}
```

The main program code that calls the ID generation

```
Weekend student1 = new Weekend();
student1.addDetails("Jane", "Malabe", 'F', 1990, "DS", "QA");
String studentid = student1.generateID();
```

I know that we can give a lowerbound by adding a lowervalue to the generated random int. However, we were asked to carry it out this way. I would like to know whether my code will work. As in, will it loop until the ID is longer than 4 characters?

Furthermore, is it possible to carry this out using try catch as well?

Thanks alot!

edit: I removed the try catch block and used a throw instead.

Comment: If you're wondering whether your code will work, why don't you try it?

Comment: Extend from `java.lang.RuntimeException`, this removes the need for `try` and `catch`. By the way, just use a predefined _RuntimeException_, there are so many already defined: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/RuntimeException.html PS you may throw an exception just by calling `throw new myException();`.

Comment: Thanks @paladin. Yeah, I agree but they basically asked us to create the IDInvalidException in the question. The question has more jumbled code we have to fill in, so it's a bit of a mess. I'll try it all out as soon as its finished.

Comment: Something like `new String("")` or `new String("IT" + String.valueOf(intRandom))` is unnecessary.  `""` is already a string and `new String("")` just will create a new string for that already existing one. Sure, the garbage collector will take care of that, though you could simply assign `String studentId = "";` or `String ID = "IT" + intRandom;`. While your `generateID()` method does declare to throw `IDInvalidException` it is not thrown at all. Did you actually mean `String studenId = new IDGeneration().newID(); if (studentID.length() < 4) { throw new IDInvalidException(studentID); } ...`?

Comment: Thanks alot @RomanVottner. Is `String studenId = new IDGeneration().newID(); if (studentID.length() < 4) { throw new IDInvalidException(studentID); } ...` refering the Main class? If so, it was basically given to us as a question, and we had to fill in the code to a given description. I don't think we were allowed to change the code in the Main class. However, I managed to run the code and figure it out. Thanks alot!

Comment: Also @RomanVottner if I could clarify. Let us say that a method `A()`throws an exception. Then the code `objectname.A()` that calls must try and catch the thrown exception right? If not, that exception should be thrown by the main class.

Comment: Depends on whether the exception is a checked or unchecked exception. The former ones need to be handled in some way, the latter one can but don't have to be. Checked exceptions derive from `Excepton` while unchecked ones from `RuntimeException` if you will. I.e. if you declare a method to throw an `InvalidArgumentException` you don't need to wrap this method arround a try-catch block as it derives from `RuntimeException`. At some point you should handle any kind of exceptions though unless you explicitely want to exit the application showing the current stacktrace to the user in logs/console